# Unable to install a python package on zsh but successful on bash

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, pip, zsh

I want to install papermill[s3] using pip. 
The command indicated in the traceback is: `pip install papermill[s3]`. However, when I run the command: `pip3 install papermill[s3]`, I get a following traceback:

```
zsh: no matches found: papermill[s3]
```

I tried going through the documentation but they state the exact same syntax.

Source: https://github.com/nteract/papermill

Update:
I am able to install the same when I enter `bash` and not `zsh` terminal.

Comment: How did you know there is a package named `papermill[s3]`?

Comment: https://github.com/nteract/papermill
Added in the ques, thanks!

Comment: It works on my side, but I use bash, not sure, wait others comments.

Comment: adding this to question, it works when i ran it via bash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Square brackets in zsh have special meanings but in MOST circumstances maybe you just have to escape them by putting (backslash) before them. See [this](http://kinopyo.com/zh/blog/escape-square-bracket-by-default-in-zsh)

So with next which do escape string, it works:

```
pip3 install papermill\[s3\]
```

Comment: you're a genius!

Comment: do you think this question is indexable enough for people to arrive at this point - where zsh is different from bash?

Comment: @AviralSrivastava It's fine now, I think. Just add `bash` & `zsh` tag will be better.

Comment: `pip install 'papermill[s3]'`